Positioning Fixed Effects before Num.Obs in Modelsummary
Thanks to Vincent for a wonderful package! I was wondering if there was a way to position Fixed Effects information row right before the Num.Obs row in the modelsummary table? I already use add_rows to add Dep Var info on the first row however so if we could combine both it would be great here is the code:


library(fixest)
library(modelsummary)
library(dplyr)

# Example model list from fixest
data(trade)
est_list_1 <- list(
  feols(log(Euros) ~ log(dist_km) + log(Year) | Destination, trade),
  feols(log(Euros) ~ log(dist_km) + log(Year) | Origin, trade)

insert_row <- function(x) {
  out <- c("Dep. Var.", names(dvnames(x)))
  out <- data.frame(as.list(out))
  attr(out, "position") <- 0
  return(out)
}

modelsummary(est_list_1, add_rows = insert_row(est_list_1))


Here is an output of that code

+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
|                 | (1)             | (2)        |
+=================+=================+============+
| Dep. Var.       | log(Euros)      | log(Euros) |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
| log(dist_km)    | -2.3870         | -1.6726    |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
|                 | (0.189)         | (0.200)    |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
| log(Year)       | 69.6695         | 75.3257    |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
|                 | (17.216)        | (6.619)    |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
| Num.Obs.        | 38325           | 38325      |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
| R2              | 0.272           | 0.347      |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
| R2 Adj.         | 0.272           | 0.347      |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
| R2 Within       | 0.185           | 0.111      |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
| R2 Within Adj.  | 0.185           | 0.111      |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
| AIC             | 186085.2        | 181925.3   |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
| BIC             | 186230.6        | 182070.7   |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
| RMSE            | 2.74            | 2.60       |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
| Std.Errors      | by: Destination | by: Origin |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
| # FE            | 15              | 15         |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
| FE: Destination | X               |            |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+
| FE: Origin      |                 | X          |
+-----------------+-----------------+------------+ 


If we could move any Fixed Effect info right after all the coefficients and above the GOF statistics, it would be great. Sort of following this format:

Edit: packageVersion("modelsummary")
1 ‘2.2.0.1’

You can use gof_map to change the order of model information that appears in the bottom panel. This is documented with many examples on the website: https://modelsummary.com
